# iOS Modifying CALayer Using View Attributes After Constraints are Applied

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, calayer

Say I have a UICollectionViewCell (applies to any view however) with a UIImageView (again, any view) and I'm **not using** auto-layout. I want to apply a CAGradientLayer on top. Inside the `awakeFromNib` I could use the frame.size of the image view to create a bezier path for my shadow. This works great!

The problem is if I use auto-layout constraints to size and position that image view inside the collection view cell. Constraints aren't applied at the `awakeFromNib` callback point. So I can't use the first approach. My solution thus far has been to defer that CALayer positioning to `layoutSubviews`. This is not an optimal solution because it is called multiple times and you can actually see the CALayer reposition itself.